# dplyr: Renaming variables with rename_

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub

I am trying to rename several variables in a chain:

```
df_foo = data_frame(
  a.a = 1:10,
  "b...b" = 1:10,
  "cc..d" = 1:10
)

df_foo %>% 
  rename_(
    .dots = setNames(
      names(.),
      gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", names(.)))
  )
```

This works fine, but when there is a space in the name of one of the variables:

```
df_foo = data_frame(
  a.a = 1:10,
  "b...b" = 1:10,
  "c c..d" = 1:10
)

df_foo %>% 
  rename_(
    .dots = setNames(
      names(.),
      gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", names(.)))
  )
```

I get this error:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:3: unexpected symbol
1: c c..d
      ^
```

I am not sure where this stems from since when I run `gsub` directly:

```
setNames(
      names(df_foo),
      gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", names(df_foo)))
```

I do not get an error. Not sure what is going on here.

---

This is now raised as [issue #2391](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2391) on the `dplyr` GH issues page.

Comment: Would you be open to a non-`dplyr` solution? Spaces in variable names are not handled well by that package.

Comment: @Hugh I think I already have the non-`dplyr` solution, which is to run `gsub` on the names directly. I would just want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: The error can be traced to `lazyeval::as.lazy('aa a')` returning a parsing error. Since `dplyr` heavily relies on `lazyeval` internally, this is likely hard to solve.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks. I will raise this as a bug on the `dplyr` issues page. If you write up your analysis of the bug, I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: I strongly suggest you never use variable names with spaces. They are a pain and will often cause more trouble than they are worth.

Here is the cause of this error.

`rename_` dispatches to `dplyr:::rename_.data.frame`. First line of that function is:

```
dots <- lazyeval::all_dots(.dots, ...)
```

That `lazyeval` function will then call `lazyeval::as.lazy_dots`, which uses `lazyeval::as.lazy`, which itself uses `lazyeval:::as.lazy.character` which calls `lazy_(parse(text = x)[[1]], env)`. Now, `parse()` expects valid R expression as its text argument:

> text: character vector. The text to parse. Elements are treated as if they were lines of a file. (from `help("parse")`)

This is why `rename_` doesn't seem to like character vectors with spaces and we get "Error in `parse(text = x)`":

```
lazyeval:::as.lazy(names(df_foo)[2])
```

> ```
> <lazy>
>   expr: b...b
>   env:  <environment: base>
> ```

```
lazyeval:::as.lazy(names(df_foo)[3])
```

> ```
> Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:3: unexpected symbol
> 1: c c..d
>       ^
> ```

I'm not aware of a solution, other then just using base for this simple renaming.

Comment: We could go further: `as.lazy.character` calls `lazy_(parse(text = x)[[1]], env)` ; and `?parse` says that `text: character vector. The text to parse. Elements are treated as if they were lines of a file` ie. parse expects a valid R expression, which forbids the space in this case.